# Howto pass overly protective corporate firewall

Tags: certificates, vpn, corporate-policy, censorship

My Corporate Network was always being monitored, but a few days ago they started to block and censor all HTTPS traffic.
Recently IT guys forged certificates for all major HTTPS web sites and acts as a man in the middle. The rest of the HTTPS does not work at all. I cannot and will not connect to a secure site knowing that they are spoofing everything.
TOR does not work too, because the SOCS port is restricted too.
The only open port seems to be 80, but I am not sure.

What are my options? OpenVPN, SSHTunnel? And How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are ways to do this I would advise you not to try. Chances are good that circumventing your company's security is against policy and could get you disciplined or fired. If you are having trouble doing your job because of the new policies then talk to your management. If all it does is block facebook then deal with it, and get a smartphone or tablet to do your personal stuff.

Comment: Mine is a bit curiosity and a bit trying to cope with a challenge. Thanks anyway, I reckon you are right.

Comment: When I get enough internet points this is getting downvoted because this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 2):

I used SSH Tunnel to bypass my college corporate style firewall. Looks like you are in extreme conditions of Internet Filtering and Censoring.

Do you have to use Proxy to connect to the Internet?

Anyways, follow this guide which helped me greatly. 
http://polishlinux.org/apps/ssh-tunneling-to-bypass-corporate-firewalls/

Here also, TOR was not working but they have opened the port 443 for SSL connections and hence that can be used to bypass. If the port is blocked then you would need to scan the ports for **Outbound** connections.

One more thing is that even if you use the SSH tunnel or the OpenVPN , a well prepared Admin will be able to monitor your data that it is encrypted and can simply issue you a notice.

Also, **your IT Admin may not be very happy seeing that you are bypassing the restrictions set by them. You could just go and ask them nicely and remember that the restrictions are many times there to protect the organization.**

Answer (score 0):

Tor can be used on that port, have you read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/437844/using-tor-behind-a-proxy-when-just-port-80-is-open) post or [this](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en) tor documentation about bridges?